# What is the name of the cable (RJ45 to RJ45) that can be used to connect from a KVM to Cisco serial port?

Tags: cisco, switch, kvm-virtualization, serial

As everybody knows Cisco's console ports are RJ45. However, the cable they come bundled with is DB9 to RJ45. We have a KVM that allows managing network devices via a serial port but the port on the KVM is also RJ45, not DB9. What is the name of the cable to allow this connection (serial RJ45 to RJ45). Note: the standard Ethernet patch cable is also RJ45 to RJ45 but does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct, standard ethernet cables won't work due to the wiring sequence - cisco uses what's called a "rollover cable" for their serial consoles. An example of the pin-out for rollover can be found here:

http://pinouts.ru/NetworkCables/rj45_rollover_pinout.shtml

It's as simple as pin 8 on one end is swapped to pin 1 on the other end, pin 7 to pin 2, etc. All the way down the cable.

If you have some Cat-5 cable, RJ-45 ends, a crimper, and the know-how to crimp your own cables - you can make your own rollovers fairly easily!  If you don't wish to do that, I'd suggest searching for "Cisco RJ-45 Rollover" or similar in order to find vendors from which you can purchase RJ-45 to RJ-45 rollover cables.

**P.S**:  Double-check the documentation of your KVM - some KVMs that allow serial management require their own proprietary adapters for it, even if the port on the KVM is RJ-45.  If it does require a proprietary adapter, there's a chance that it will support standard RJ-45.

Comment: Rollover cable is different from Crossover (one used to directly connect two hosts)?

Comment: Yes, crossover has a different pinout as well. It has a different crossing pattern rather than straight "rolling over" - (see http://pinouts.ru/NetworkCables/Ethernet100BaseT4Crossover.shtml) - so a crossover cable won't work in lieu of a rollover cable.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Haymaker, I think this is also a good page comparing 3 types on the same page with explanations: http://www.computercablestore.com/straight-through_crossover_rollover.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Haymaker beat me to it...

You don't say what Cisco device or what KVM, but chances are you want what Cisco calls a rollover cable:

```
Pin 1 on one end connects to Pin 8 on the other
Pin 2                        Pin 7
Pin 3                        Pin 6
Pin 4                        Pin 5
etc.
Pin 8                        Pin 1
```

This is basically a null-modem cable but with RJ connectors instead of DB.  Here's a link to a different [Cisco doc that describes console pinouts.](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps214/products_tech_note09186a00801f5d85.shtml)

Comment: Thanks! I spend half my day sometimes reading cisco docs yet I didn't even think to link one. :)

Comment: yesterday I made my first rollover cable! Thanks both Ward and Haymaker for spending time to answer! Upvoted both answers.